# matching two graphs with the lowest error

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, graph-algorithm

I have two graphs that I would like to match (I am not sure this is the world I'm looking for).

In my first graph nodes represents teams (node value represents the number of people in the team) and links represent how close teams are on a scale of 1 to 5. Two teams working a lot together will have a stronger link than two teams that work sometimes together.

In my second graph nodes represent spaces (node value represents the available places in the space) and links represent how close the spaces are. If two spaces are on the same floor they will have a stronger link than two spaces that are not on the same floor.

I need to distribute the teams in the available spaces minimizing the distance between each linked team (two teams that have a strong link would be at the same floor for example).

My first question is : do you have a magic recipe that would solve this problem ? 
My second question : If not, do you know in what direction I need to check (algorithm that could be reworked, lectures, articles ...).

Thank you very much. 
Thoma

Comment: Did you already define an evaluation function? I.e. a function which is able to _quantify_ the suitability of a solution?

Comment: How many teams do you have?

Comment: Are the graphs complete, i.e. there is a link between every pair of teams/pair of spaces?

Comment: Are there more spaces than teams or are the numbers equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with some people, it seems that it might not be the best solution. 
I will look in the direction of solvers to be abble to have define constraints.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in part, apparently there is no known polynomial-time algorithm to solve the problem, as the problem includes the [graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) problem as a subproblem. This problem is neither known to be NP-complete nor has a polynomial algorithm been found.

More precisely, suppose that the room graph is exactly the team graph, where edges are not weighted. As an optimal solution would match each team to the corresponding room, an algorithm for the problem in the question would be able to identify the input graphs to be isomorphic.

Comment: I’m not seeing the connection to subgraph isomorphism or graph isomorphism here. Can you elaborate a bit?